# How can I get a profile picture of an athlete from web page

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I want to display the picture of the athlete depending on the selection of the player. I am using JSOUP in order to retrive the rest of the information like stats etc...I am havina a problem because the html keeps on changing by every player. I can feed the html the name but I dont know the id of evey player on selection. any ideas?

HTNL example : http://www.rotoworld.com/player/nba/784/zach-randolph/1

I can push the name when the player is selected (zach-randolph) but not his code(784)...

Update-- Maybe I can do a google image search on the name and retrieve the first result anyone know how to do this?

CODE:

```
public class ImagetestdroidActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView image = null;
//ImageView image2 = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    GetPlayerTask fetch = new GetPlayerTask();
 String phrase = "Lebron James";
    String delims = "[ ]+";
    String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Token"+i+":"+tokens[i]);
    }
    fetch.execute(tokens[0], tokens[1], "nba");

}

public String getimage(String html) throws IOException
{
     try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
            Element e = doc.select("div.playerphoto > img").first();
            // If you want absolute path
            String imgSrcAbs =  e.attr("abs:src");      
            System.out.println(imgSrcAbs);
            // Or , If you want relative path
            String imgSrcRelative =  e.attr("src"); 
            System.out.println(imgSrcRelative);
            return imgSrcAbs;
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {             
        }

    return null;
}
public void onPlayerFound(String result) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("in ONPLAYERFOUNFD"+result);
     String imagehtml= getimage("http://www.rotoworld.com/"+result+"/1");
     try 
     {
         System.out.println("IMG HTML "+imagehtml);
         URL feedImage = new URL(imagehtml);
         HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)feedImage.openConnection();
         InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        image.setImageBitmap(img);

     } 
     catch (MalformedURLException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}

class GetPlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final String TAG = null;
    AndroidHttpClient   mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111107 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.24");
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = null;
        String url = Uri.parse("http://www.rotoworld.com").buildUpon()
                .appendEncodedPath("content/playersearch.aspx")
                .appendQueryParameter("searchname", params[0] + " " + params[1])
                .build().toString();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.rotoworld.com");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$btnAdvancedSearch", "Search"));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$radSportSearch", params[2].toUpperCase()));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$tbFirstNameSearch", params[0]));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$tbLastNameSearch", params[1]));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$tbHeaderSearchBox", "LAST NAME, FIRST NAME"));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$headlinesNFL$hideHeadlineSport", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$siteheader$hidpage", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTARGUMENT", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTTARGET", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTVALIDATION", "/wEWEALJp4KIBAKHlvL3BgLA+sClCQK5vLryBgKn1MPhBAK9kM36BQKj89HmAwLA+vrmBAKk7ayNDgKj85nnAwKU87XnAwKurM6nDAK++qLmBAKD2r2iBgKQ+47mAgK//t/aB6qbH1ovSUf6LkMO7LTmIW5EbRu5"));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE", "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"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

            HttpResponse response = mClient.execute(post);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 302) {
                Header location = response.getFirstHeader("Location");
                if (location != null) {
                    result = location.getValue();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable perform request", e);
        }

        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Call whatever method you want to notify your Activity
        // that you've found the player in question
        try {
            System.out.println("getplayer"+result);
            onPlayerFound(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a search function on the site you're scraping that you can emulate using a HttpClient and a HttpPost, as shown in the following example.

First and foremost, use a HttpClient - in this case AndroidHttpClient. We mimic the User-Agent of a real browser just in case:

```
mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111107 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.24", this);
```

Then - an AsyncTask that will perform the network operation:

```
class GetPlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = null;
        String url = Uri.parse("http://www.rotoworld.com").buildUpon()
                .appendEncodedPath("content/playersearch.aspx")
                .appendQueryParameter("searchname", params[0] + " " + params[1])
                .build().toString();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.rotoworld.com");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$btnAdvancedSearch", "Search"));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$radSportSearch", params[2].toUpperCase()));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$tbFirstNameSearch", params[0]));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$tbLastNameSearch", params[1]));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$tbHeaderSearchBox", "LAST NAME, FIRST NAME"));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$headlinesNFL$hideHeadlineSport", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cp1$siteheader$hidpage", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTARGUMENT", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTTARGET", ""));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTVALIDATION", "/wEWEALJp4KIBAKHlvL3BgLA+sClCQK5vLryBgKn1MPhBAK9kM36BQKj89HmAwLA+vrmBAKk7ayNDgKj85nnAwKU87XnAwKurM6nDAK++qLmBAKD2r2iBgKQ+47mAgK//t/aB6qbH1ovSUf6LkMO7LTmIW5EbRu5"));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE", "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"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

            HttpResponse response = mClient.execute(post);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 302) {
                Header location = response.getFirstHeader("Location");
                if (location != null) {
                    result = location.getValue();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable perform request", e);
        }

        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Call whatever method you want to notify your Activity
        // that you've found the player in question
        onPlayerFound(result);
    }
}
```

The `BasicNameValuePair`s above were scraped with 2-3s effort on their search page using FireBug. The response from a "successful search" is a redirect message (302), containing the location of the player page - i.e. the identifier you required to download the image.

The `GetPlayerTask` would be used like this:

```
    GetPlayerTask fetch = new GetPlayerTask();
    // FirstName, LastName, Category (NBA/etc./etc.)
    fetch.execute("Gerald", "Henderson", "nba");
```

This would return a path relative to www.rotoworld.com, e.g.

```
"/player/nba/1614/gerald-henderson"
```

Comment: Thanks again!! I dont understand one thing. on the onPostExecute there is a method onPlayerFound. How do I notify my activity and transfer the result to the activity? Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: You are expected to implement a method in your Activity, e.g. "void onPlayerFound(String playerUrl)" - this will then be called by the GetPlayerTask (that you place inside your activity class) when the download has completed. If no player match was found the "onPlayerFound()" method will receive `null`.

Comment: Does the GetPlayerTask need to be an inner Class of the activity Class?

Comment: If you want to use it as a "normal" class just remove the "onPostExecute()" and in every activity you use it in you subclass the GetPlayerTask and override the onPostExecute..

Comment: OK I did a inner class but still getting null added my methods above

Comment: You shouldn't edit responses like that - updates like that go in your original question - but . why are you creating a new Activity like that ? That won't work at all.

Comment: Sorry for editing your responce.Thanks again for your time!I am getting the error when retrieving the image from the webpage. I updated my code and error.Please help thanks

Comment: Never mind figured it out!!! updated my code above for anyone who will need this in the furure!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String url = "http://www.rotoworld.com/player/nba/784/zach-randolph/1";
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element e = doc.select("div.playerphoto > img").first();
        // If you want absolute path
        String imgSrcAbs =  e.attr("abs:src");      
        System.out.println(imgSrcAbs);
        // Or , If you want relative path
        String imgSrcRelative =  e.attr("src"); 
        System.out.println(imgSrcRelative);

        } 
    catch (IOException e) {             
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!I tried it but getting the error above.I updated my code.Please help thanks for your time!!

Comment: Never mind figured it out!!! updated my code above for anyone who will need this in the furure!!